# Remove everything before a question mark and hyphen "? - "

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove everything before "? - "
I've run this

```
gsub(".*? - ", "",  "Question X? - Text_A - Text_B")
[1] "Text_B"
```

It's removed everything before the other hyphen in the text.
The result I'm after is this

```
[1] "Text_A - Text_B"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try `sub` instead of `gsub`. The "g" means "global" (remove all).

Comment: `?` has special meaning in regex you need to escape it to match them literally. `gsub(".*\\? - ", "",  "Question X? - Text_A - Text_B")`

Comment: thank you both for your responses, it works. Thanks